# Numbers in date are not displaying in Marathi language in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display today's date in "Marathi" language.But the numbers from date are not displaying in Marathi language.
I have written following code lines to achieve it.
(flutter-3.0.4 stable)

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
```

```
String todaysDate = DateFormat('d MMMM, yyyy', "mr_IN").format(currentDate);
```

Actual output is:

```
20 डिसेंबर, 2022
```

But I want to display:

```
२० डिसेंबर, २०२२
```

As we can see, numbers from date are not in Marathi language.

I have also wrote the below extension method but that also not resolve that issue:

```
extension ExtendedString on String {
  String get toMarathi {
    String dateInMarathi = this;
    if (dateInMarathi.contains("0")) {
      dateInMarathi = dateInMarathi.replaceAll("0", "०");
    }
    if (dateInMarathi.contains("1")) {
      dateInMarathi = dateInMarathi.replaceAll("1", "१");
    }
    if (dateInMarathi.contains("2")) {
      dateInMarathi = dateInMarathi.replaceAll("2", "२");
    }
    if (dateInMarathi.contains("3")) {
      dateInMarathi = dateInMarathi.replaceAll("3", "३");
    }
    if (dateInMarathi.contains("4")) {
      dateInMarathi = dateInMarathi.replaceAll("4", "४");
    }
    if (dateInMarathi.contains("5")) {
      dateInMarathi = dateInMarathi.replaceAll("5", "५");
    }
    if (dateInMarathi.contains("6")) {
      dateInMarathi = dateInMarathi.replaceAll("6", "६");
    }
    if (dateInMarathi.contains("7")) {
      dateInMarathi = dateInMarathi.replaceAll("7", "७");
    }
    if (dateInMarathi.contains("8")) {
      dateInMarathi = dateInMarathi.replaceAll("8", "८");
    }
    if (dateInMarathi.contains("9")) {
      dateInMarathi = dateInMarathi.replaceAll("9", "९");
    }
    return dateInMarathi;
  }
}
```

Comment: it's the font!! does you have app/textwidget has a proper Marathi font set?

Comment: ^does your app...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
extension ExtendedString on String {
  String toMarathi {
    return this.replaceAll("0", "०").replaceAll("1", "१").replaceAll("2", "२").replaceAll("3", "३").replaceAll("4", "४").replaceAll("5", "५").replaceAll("6", "६").replaceAll("7", "७").replaceAll("8", "८").replaceAll("9", "९");
  }
}
```

---

```
"${DateTime.now().day}, ${DateTime.now().month}, ${DateTime.now().year}".toMarathi()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code refer some links [GlobalMaterialLocalizations](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_localizations/GlobalMaterialLocalizations-class.html), [initializeDateFormatting](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/date_symbol_data_http_request/initializeDateFormatting.html):

import below package for

```
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
```

add `initializeDateFormatting()` inside `initState`

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    initializeDateFormatting();
    super.initState();
  }
```

your date code

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
String todaysDate = DateFormat('d MMMM, yyyy', "mr").format(currentDate);

print(todaysDate);
```

Your Widget:

```
Text(todaysDate),
```

Full Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeDateFormatting();
  }

  DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String todaysDate = DateFormat('d MMMM, yyyy', "mr").format(currentDate);
    print(todaysDate);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(todaysDate),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result-> [image]